# Remap <C-(Left|Right|Up|Down)> for Neovim on OSX

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, keymapping, remap, neovim

I'm trying to remap C-*any arrow key* in Neovim on my Mac to switch windows.

My `.config/nvim/init.vim` has the following:

```
" Basic key mappings and controls
" -------------------------------

" Simpler pane moving.
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
nnoremap <C-Down> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-Up> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-Right> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-Left> <C-W><C-H>
```

However when I restart nvim, the C-J/K/L/H combos work but the C-arrow key combos do not work. What else do I have to do on my Mac to get such remappings to work when I'm working in OSX's default terminal app, or tmux using zsh?

Comment: Have you tried this with an empty init.vim except for those commands? More often than not it's other plugins/mappings interfering.